# Rewrite "button.Click += ..." using ICommand in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms, icommand

I am using an external SDK.

```
namespace ProSimSDK 
{
    public class ArmedFailure
   {
     ...
     public static event ArmedFailureEventDelegate onNew;
     public void Reset();
     ...
   }
}

namespace ProSimSDK
{
   public delegate void ArmedFailureEventDelegate(ArmedFailure armedFailure);
}
```

I have some trouble when I try to rewrite some Winform code by WPF. In Winform:

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    ArmedFailure.onNew += new ArmedFailureEventDelegate(ArmedFailure_onNew);
}

// This function will be called when a new armedFailure is received
void ArmedFailure_onNew(ArmedFailure armedFailure)
{
      //Here is the code I need to rewrite in WPF.
      removeButton.Click += new EventHandler(delegate(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            failure.Reset();
        });
}
```

In WPF, I use a listbox. With some guide, I am using ListBox Template and Command.
In Window1.xaml:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="ListBoxItemTemplate">
    <Grid>
        <TextBlock x:Name="TB" Margin="5,10,5,5" Grid.Column="2" Height="23" Text="{Binding}" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
        <Button HorizontalAlignment="Right" Grid.Column="3" Margin="500,10,5,0" CommandParameter="{Binding}" Command="{Binding ElementName=UC_Failures_Setting, Path=OnClickCommand}" Width="80" Click="Button_Click">remove</Button>
    </Grid>
</DataTemplate>

<ListBox x:Name="listbox" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource ListBoxItemTemplate}" Margin="0,661,982,0" SelectionChanged="ListBox_SelectionChanged">
```

Window1.xaml.cs

```
public Window1()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    //How to implement the same functionality of "removeButton.Click += new EventHandler(delegate(object sender, EventArgs e) {failure.Reset();});" shown in Winform???
    OnClickCommand = new ActionCommand(x => listbox.Items.Remove(x));
}
```

ActionCommand.cs:

```
 public class ActionCommand: ICommand
 {
    private readonly Action<object> Action;
    private readonly Predicate<object> Predicate;

    public ActionCommand(Action<object> action) : this(action, x => true)
    {

    }
    public ActionCommand(Action<object> action, Predicate<object> predicate)
    {
        Action = action;
        Predicate = predicate;
    }

    public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
    {
        return Predicate(parameter);
    }
    public void Execute(object parameter)
    {
        Action(parameter);
    }

    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged
    {
        add
        {
            CommandManager.RequerySuggested += value;
        }
        remove
        {
            CommandManager.RequerySuggested -= value;
        }
    }
}
```

How does the button in my listbox implement the same functionality of

```
removeButton.Click += new EventHandler(delegate(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{ failure.Reset(); });
```

shown in Winform? In WPF I cannot write it this way. Thanks.

Comment: The easiest way in my oppinion would be learning exactly how binding works and following the MVVM way of working, then binding the click event of your button to a method on your ViewModel via XAML of your view.
When using WPF,  MVVM is very close to the standard.

Comment: When starting to process of learning MVVM in WPF, the 2 best options would either be SimpleMVVMToolkit(My fav) or MVVMLight........If you want to die before you understand everything, use PRISM

Comment: I found that the best way to actually learn what WPF was doing with bindings was to try and reimplement parts of those libraries in my own library, taking my best guess as to how to handle it. Then looking at the real library's source to see how close I got.  It isn't fast, but it is informative.  Coming right in with an MVVM library felt like I was learning the library instead of learning WPF and MVVM.  Of course, don't try to do that with production level code.  Use "toy" apps to experiment.

Comment: Thanks for the suggesstions. I have started to learn MVVM, binding, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if `ListBox` is populated with `ArmedFailure` items, then the parameter which command receives, should be `ArmedFailure` item.

```
OnClickCommand = new ActionCommand
( 
   x => 
   {
       var failure = (ArmedFailure)x;
       failure.Reset();
       listbox.Items.Remove(x);
   }
);
```

everything that was in Button.Click handler in WinForms becomes part of ICommand.Execute in wpf

Comment: Thank you very much! ListBox should be populated with ArmedFailure items.@ASh